# Fluent NHibernate Foreign Key is Null, from lookup table

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent

I have a lookup table that contains products (Product table) a CustomerOrder table that contains order details and an OrderLines table that contains a line per product ordered.

So the entities look something like this

### OrderLine

```
Id
..stuff..
Product
```

### Product

```
Id
ProductInfo
```

The tables look the same except instead of Product there is a ProductId foreign key.
The mapping overrides look like this

For OrderLine

```
mapping.HasOne(x => x.Product)
        .Fetch.Join()
        .Cascade.All();
```

That is it really. The problem is this, with the above statement a null gets inserted as the ProductId foreign key, if I remove the mapping it works correctly, but this causes multiple (as in thousands) of selects further on in the system. What am I missing here ? If I put a virtual back to OrderLine in Product, then NHibernate tries to update both entities (i.e. it tries to insert a new record in the product table, which already exists. How do I tell NHibernate about this relationship, without it trying to update Products ?

Help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help at all, but are you sure HasOne() is appropriate here.  Can any two OrderLines refer to the same Product?  If so, then I think References() is more suitable.

Comment: Yes, two different OrderLines can refer to the same Product. I have tried doing this with References, but maybe I am missing something, this is what I tried mapping.References(x => x.Product).Cascade.All(); Doing that fills in the foreign key, but the problem is that in other parts of the system when it tries to get to that Product from OrderLines NHibernate uses single selects on the Product table, as opposed to a join. So the reference solves the key being null, but then doesn't do a join, the HasOne forces the join, but fill the null.

Comment: Does mapping.References(x => x.Product).Not.LazyLoad(); force this behavior by chance?

Comment: You were indeed correct, the References is what I needed, the multiple select thing came from another part of the code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I converted my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mapping.References(x => x.Product)` instead of `mapping.HasOne(x => x.Product)`.